# open generated pdf file in new tab instead of downloading..Web API

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api

.Net 4.6.1 C#

I generate a pdf file at runtime and can download it successfully. I want to open the newly created pdf file in a new tab instead of downloading it. Here's my code (Web API 2.1 method):

```
  public HttpResponseMessage ToPDF(string cn)
    {

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream = GeneratePDF();


        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "file.pdf"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");


        return result;


    }
```

I thought this would work, but it doesn't. I have target="_blank" on my anchor tag as well. How do i open my newly generated pdf file in a new tab instead of the browser wanting to download it to the user's hard drive? Thanks

Comment: You need to change the content disposition from attachment to inline (btw there is a constant for that `System.Net.Mime.DispositionTypeNames.Inline`). See http://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml

Comment: @ckuri - that was it. Please post as an answer so i can give you proper credit. Thank you

Comment: As you proposed, I posted it as an answer.

Comment: @BoundForGlory can you please tell me, how did you call this web api from your browser using target _blank?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from David Mkheyan's proposal of setting the proper MIME type, you also need to change the content disposition from `attachment` to `inline`.

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue(System.Net.Mime.DispositionTypeNames.Inline)
    {
        FileName = "file.pdf"
    };
```

According to https://www.iana.org/assignments/cont-disp/cont-disp.xhtml `attachment` means "user controlled display" and `inline` is "displayed automatically".

Comment: awesome job mate!

Comment: I am still not able to open in a new tab using inline

Answer (score 1):

Just change the Media type from application/octet-stream to application/pdf .It should work.I guess you can also change the return type to FileResult instead of HttpResponseMessage.

 `result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");`

Comment: thanks for replying, but it still wants to download the pdf and not open it in a new tab

Answer (score 1):

Just return PhysicalFileResult and use HttpGet method ,url will open pdf file

```
public ActionResult GetPublicLink()
 {
         path = @"D:\Read\x.pdf";
        return new PhysicalFileResult(path, "application/pdf");
}
```